# how convert varbinary(image) to ntext in sql and sqllite

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

How convert a `varbinary(image)` to `ntext` in SQL and SQLite?

I want to convert data type `varbinary` to `ntext`

```
CAST(NEW.[PhotoContent] AS NTEXT)
```

but I get an error:

> Explicit conversion from data type varbinary(max) to ntext is not allowed.

How can I turn these two types together?

Comment: can you elaborate why you want do that?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Why would you even try to? What do you expect to see in that ntext?

Comment: @ZoharPeled 
Because I want to transfer the image through Jason to Android

Comment: I know very little about android development but it seems unreasonable to pass binary data using text. I'm sure there is a better solution that does not involve casting binary data to text.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza i want image send to Database Android

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    Create function [dbo].[fn_HexToStr](@hex varbinary(Max))
>         returns varchar(Max)
>            as
>           begin
>             declare 
>             @len int,
>             @counter int,
>             @res varchar(Max),
>             @string char(16),
>             @byte binary(1)
>             set @string = '0123456789ABCDEF'
>             set @res = '0x'
>             set @len = datalength(@hex)
>             set @counter = 1
>             while(@counter <= @len)
>             begin
>             set @byte = substring(@hex, @counter, 1)
>             set @res = @res + substring(@string, 1 + @byte/16, 1) + 
>             substring(@string, 1 + @byte - (@byte/16)*16, 1)set @counter = @counter + 1
>             end
>            set @res=substring(@res,3,len(@res))
>            return @res
>     end
> ```